# Is float used when you don't know how many digits a number will have?

Tags: sql-server-2008

There are several postings on the subject of float vs. decimal. But my specific question i don't know ahead of time how many digits past the decimal point I need...it varies. Does this mean I should use float. Because with decmial, you specify a specific number of digits past the decimal point.

Comment: The important part would be to know what you want to store

Comment: no, float is used when 100% accuracy isn't required. if you need 100% accuracy, you use decimal and allocate as many digits as you need.

Comment: will sql server generate a nice error for me if i try to store more digits than i allocated in the decimal type, or will it truncate without warning ?

Comment: Depends on what you consider a "nice error".  The error I get is: `Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.`  But it is specific.